# Javascript initializing properties

Tags: javascript, regex, web, frontend

I have a small discussion with my colleague and I would like to know what other people think about this. I don't like initializing properties that might not be used. 
The regex is not in the method itself because we don't want to initialize the regex every time.

File helpers/service.js

**How I would do it:**

```
let serviceCheckRegExp = null;
export const isServiceUrl = url => {
  if (!serviceCheckRegExp) serviceCheckRegExp = new RegExp(getApi('service'),'i');
  return serviceCheckRegExp.test(url);
};
```

**How my colleague would do it:**

```
const serviceCheckRegExp = new RegExp(getApi('service'),'i');
export const isServiceUrl = url => serviceCheckRegExp.test(url);
```

Comment: Why don't you like initialising unused properties nor doing it in the method? Performance? Is the performance difference worth the added complexity you're introducing?

Comment: 2 easy lines of code vs 5 easy lines of code. I'll take the 2 any day unless there is a compelling reason not to like for example `getApi` takes 30 seconds and you don't want to wait for that without actually using it.

Comment: The regex is put outside the method because it could be called many times during some flows. But thanks for the reply:)